# How to hide div serverside by reading cookie

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using following a tutorial from here: http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/cookies-with-jquery-designing-collapsible-layouts/

This is the script I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
        $(function() {
            // SETUP:
                // When the info banner is clicked:
                $('#setup').click(function() {
                    $('#intro').css("display","none");
                    $.cookie('intro', 'collapsed');
                });
            // COOKIES
                // Info banner state
                var intro = $.cookie('intro');

            // READ THE COOKIES
                if (intro == 'collapsed') {
                  $('#intro').css("display","none");
                };
        });
</script>
```

The script hides the following div as the cookie is read:

```
<div class="feedback attention" id="intro">
            Text goes here
            <a id="setup" href="#">Ok I get it, please hide this</a> 
</div>
```

Everything work great but when the page loads the div is shown for a split second. I guess the solution is to present two different pieces of markup serverside according to the cookie info. I have no idea how to go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page load, you could use php to check the cookie, and then add a hidden class. Something like `<div class="<?= $_COOKIE['intro'] == 'collapsed' ? 'hidden':'' ?>">`

Edit:

In CSS then, you can add something like `.hidden { display: none; }` and use jQuery to add or remove that class.

Comment: Also, sorry for the short hand. `<?` is the same as `<?php` on some servers. And I used tertiary if statements, which can be confusing as well, but they save space.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* just do something like:

```
<?php

if($_COOKIE['intro'] != 'collapsed') {\

    //echo div...

}
```

Comment: nope, because in that case the div is REMOVED thus the page need to be reloaded for displaying it back. I believe the author wants it to work in "2.0 - way" ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using PHP:

```
<?php if($_COOKIE['intro'] != 'collapsed'){ ?>

<div class="feedback attention" id="intro">
            Text goes here
            <a id="setup" href="#">Ok I get it, please hide this</a> 
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

To completely remove the div rather than just hide it.

Comment: I believe the author wants it to work in "2.0 - way" ;) - to be hidden (and displayed back again) dynamically.

Comment: Based on the id name, it looks more like a nag screen like "hey you should do this and that" to me.

Answer (score 1):

check `$_COOKIE` array for 'intro'

```
if ($_COOKIE['intro'] == 'collapsed') 
//...
```

simply, add some kind of "hidden" class to the div, or specify it like `style="display: none;"`

//edit
actually, by adding the "style" attribute you ensure that the div is not displayed as soon as get parsed, while using "class" property might cause interval while waiting for CSS file.

thus

```
<div<?= ($_COOKIE['intro'] == 'collapsed') ? ' style="display: none"' : '' ?>> ..</div>
```

is best here.